# How can you assert that a given contentView is set using Robolectric?

Tags: android, android-2.1-eclair, robolectric

Given the following sample `onCreate()`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && (null != extras.getString("myVar")))
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.success);
    }
        else
        {
                setContentView(R.layout.failure);
        }

}
```

What I want to do, is to unit test this activity to make sure I can get either content view set depending on the extras that are passed in when the activity is created.

I have the following so far in my Robolectric test :

```
@Test
public void testNullExtrasSetsFailureView()
{
    myActivity.onCreate(null);
        // This is the bit I'm struggling with, how to obtain content view?
    assertThat("the view the onCreate loads..", equalTo(R.layout.failure))
}
```

How can I achieve this? I've had a look through the API and I couldn't see any obvious way of locating the content view, other than `findViewById()` but I want the layout not an individual view item.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try the method `getContentView()` on [ShadowActivity](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/javadoc/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/shadows/ShadowActivity.html):

```
import com.xtremelabs.robolectric.Robolectric._

assertEquals(R.id.failure, shadowOf(myActivity).getContentView().getId())
```

Make sure that your layout has an id:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/failure"
```

Hope that helps.